# How to solve JSON Error for Android application ?

Tags: java, android, json

Here is Error log:

```
03-13 10:00:15.778: W/System.err(2558): org.json.JSONException: No value for objects
03-13 10:00:15.778: W/System.err(2558):     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
03-13 10:00:15.778: W/System.err(2558):     at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:544)
03-13 10:00:15.778: W/System.err(2558):     at com.app.Main$ListTask.doInBackground(Main.java:104)
03-13 10:00:15.778: W/System.err(2558):     at com.app.Main$ListTask.doInBackground(Main.java:1)
03-13 10:00:15.778: W/System.err(2558):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-13 10:00:15.778: W/System.err(2558):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
03-13 10:00:15.778: W/System.err(2558):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
03-13 10:00:15.778: W/System.err(2558):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
03-13 10:00:15.778: W/System.err(2558):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
03-13 10:00:15.778: W/System.err(2558):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
03-13 10:00:15.778: W/System.err(2558):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Activity code

```
package com.app;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Main extends Activity {

    ListView List;
    ArrayList<String> listArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> Adapter;
    Context context;
    String url = "http://sandzak.today/api/1/categories/?format=json/api/projekti/10?=";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        context = this;
        List = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);
        Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.lista, listArray);
        List.setAdapter(Adapter);

        VideoListTask loaderTask = new VideoListTask();
        loaderTask.execute();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public class VideoListTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        ProgressDialog dialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() 
        {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            dialog.setTitle("Loading Category");
            dialog.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
        {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);

            try 
            {
                HttpResponse responce = client.execute(getRequest);
                StatusLine statusLine = responce.getStatusLine();
                int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();

                if(statusCode != 200)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                InputStream jsonStream = responce.getEntity().getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(jsonStream));
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while((line = reader.readLine())!=null)
                {
                    builder.append(line);
                }



                String jsonData = builder.toString();

                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonData);
                JSONObject meta = json.getJSONObject("meta");
                JSONArray objects = meta.getJSONArray("objects");

                for(int i =0; i<objects.length(); i++)
                {
                    JSONObject video = objects.getJSONObject(i);
                    listArray.add(video.getString("name"));
                }


            }
            catch (ClientProtocolException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (JSONException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Show your json response.

Comment: the exception says that `meta` has no object called `objects`

Comment: On protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) that function exists json response

Comment: Post your json response here.

Comment: post you json responce

Comment: But your **meta** tags include **objects** tag in your Json response?

Comment: there is no response from you Json URL...

Comment: HttpResponse responce = client.execute(getRequest);
                StatusLine statusLine = responce.getStatusLine();
                int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();

Comment: @user3414471 We are not talking about ti post your code. We are telling you data post that Json format data in which your data will be like meta , objects tags.

Comment: I solved this 
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonData);
    JSONArray objects = json.getJSONArray("objects");

    for(int i =0; i<objects.length(); i++)
    {
     JSONObject lista = objects.getJSONObject(i);
     listArray.add(lista.getString("name"));
    }

thanks all :D

Comment: your api does not respond.first create your API

Answer (score 0):

make a point on this node you are append the string and then you pass it to the object.In the object you need to pass the string which is key term of your json.

```
while((line = reader.readLine())!=null)
                {
                    builder.append(line);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Their is an easy way to turn a inputstrem to a string:

   `InputStream inputStream = url.openStream();
   Scanner in = new Scanner(inputStream).useDelimiter("\\A");
   String str = in.hasNext() ? in.next() : null;`
2. prefer to use `JSONObject.optXxx(field)` rather than `JSONObject.getXxx(field)`, this you don' t need to worry whether a field in the json data or whether it can convert to your desired type. Besides, `JSONObject.optXxx(field, fallback)` has a fallback value if the field doesn' t exist or cannot conver to the specific type.
3. (optional) if you would like to use `JSONObject.getXxx()`, you can first check the whether the filed in the json data using `JSONObject.has(fieldname)`

hope it' s useful.